# URL parameter validation in R Shiny?

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to validate input parameters passed through URL for a Shiny app, to prevent malicious inputs. I'm not sure if Shiny's built-in enableBookmarking function already takes care of this, however; if you type in an invalid parameter, it resets that input to the default.

1) Is this sufficient, security-wise?

2) If not, what might be a good way to fix it? I'm thinking requiring that a given input matches a drop-down list option (i.e. input$date %in% dateoptions) but I'm not sure where to put that within the app.

Here's a simple Shiny app with URL bookmarking:

```
dateoptions <- c("July 11 2016" = "07112016",
                 "July 14 2016" = "07142016",
                 "July 17 2016" = "07172016")
variableoptions <- c("GPS Altitude" = "GPS_ALT",
                     "Temperature" = "TEMPERATURE",
                     "Carbon dioxide" = "CO2")

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    selectInput('date', 'Choose date:',
                dateoptions),
    selectInput('variable', 'Choose variable:',
                variableoptions),
    uiOutput("message")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$message <- renderUI(print(paste("The URL reflects your selection of", input$date, "and", input$variable)))

observe({
  reactiveValuesToList(input) 
  session$doBookmark()
})

onBookmarked(function(url) {
  updateQueryString(url)
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.